# How to add three columns in Crystal Reports C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to make a crystal report like this in which the detail section there is item detail as well as the my expenses, and also the calculation is also there, instead in footer but these thing will be shown in three columns.

The stored procedure is good - I get all the thing in my Crystal Reports, but I am stuck in Crystal Reports settings:

```
Item           || Expenses          || Net amount
Banana 150     | Commission 10%     | Item Total 600
Apple 150      | Fare 200           | Expenses total 230
Mango 300      |                    | Net  370
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[one_complete_order]
    @order_id INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Our_orders.orderID,  
        Stock.itemname AS item,
        Stock.qty AS [Orderd Qty],
        Stock.status AS Qty,
        Stock.price AS [Cost Price],
        Stock.size AS [packing], 
        Our_orders.date, 
        vendor.Vendor_Name, vendor.Vendor_Address, 
        vendor.Contact, vendor.Vendor_Company,
        Expenses.commission, Expenses.Karaya, Expenses.labour_pay, 
        Expenses.Munishi
    FROM  
        Our_orders
    JOIN 
        Stock ON Our_orders.orderID = Stock.orderID
    JOIN 
        vendor ON vendor.VendorID = Our_orders.VendorID
    JOIN 
        Expenses ON Our_orders.orderID = Expenses.orderID
    WHERE  
        Our_orders.orderID  = @order_id
    ORDER BY
        Our_orders.date DESC;
END
```

Comment: Hey, your question is still a bit unclear. You may want to share the details of the c# code used to create and pushed  data to the report. Also, you need to share a clear expected output. The one shared here is not giving clear picture. May be you can create the expected output in an Excel sheet and share a screen shot of it.

Comment: There is  no isssue in sending the data to crystal report.. and code for sending data i used store which is above and i want my result like the above table.. i just want to distrube the the sent data to crystal report in three columns... the 1st column will consist the item detail (which is stock table in the above proc) and then the column will be expenses detail (which is expense table in the above proc) and the third column will the calculation column

Comment: the problem is when i made multiple column which make it only column for one table of data

Comment: I believe the issue you are having is the nature of how multi-column layouts work in Crystal Reports.  CR doesn't allow the user to set breaks between columns of data, so you can't chose when or where the data will break and start writing to the new column.  If everything will fit in a single column, then it will all print within that one column.  Does this sound like I am understanding your problem?

Comment: yes you got it then how i can insert the multiple columns(those columns has only one value. i.e the expenses columns in this case) and i want to show that columns in the detail section.. but when i add those columns in vertical form then it show me repeatedly with each items detail.. i just want to show the expenses in the detail section only once as well as it don't increase the height of the rows... did you got my problem now @R.McMillan sir

Comment: or in simple words to show the expenses columns in the details section in vertical form not repeated because these columns have only one value and item detail should be in horizontal form   but the row size will be according to the item detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a different number of rows for Items, Expenses, and Net Amount I would recommend using Subreports for the Expenses and Net Amount.  Allow all of your Items to print in the Details section, then insert two Subreports into the the Details section to the right of the fields for the Items data, spacing the subreports out so that they appear to be a second and third column within the details section.

You will need to determine which data field will link each Subreport to the main report.  From looking at your SQL Stored Procedure I believe OrderID would be appropriate.

You can probably use the same SQL Stored Procedure as the data source for both of your subreports.  When you create the Expenses Subreport, only use the data fields for Expenses in the Details section of the subreport, and do the same for the Net Amounts Subreport.  It will be easier to line up the rows in your subreports with the main report if you suppress all sections in the subreports except the Details sections, and then edit the format of the sub reports to remove the default border line.  That's up to you though really.  :)